# How to solve problem during reading of a json file in Python?

Tags: python, json

I`m currently programming an automated wateringsystem using Python on a Raspberry Pi. For that I want to read the content of a json file, with the following code:

```
import logging
import json

try:
    with open('/var/www/BWSWebApp/apictx.json') as file:
        jsondata = json.load(file)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('Error: File not found (ln 35)')
_logging = jsondata['main']['logging']
if _logging == True:
    _logging = '/home/pi/Desktop/BewaesserungssystemV3/data/info_log.log'
else:
    _logging = None
```

The json file is containing the following:

```
{
    "main": {
        "active": true,
        "watering": false,
        "fwatering": false,
        "ffminwatering": false,
        "humidity": 24,
        "temp": 17.6,
        "battery": 100,
        "logging": true,
        "last_watering": "27.08.2021 16:15:39",
        "l_day": 0,
        "day": 0,
        }
}
```

If I run the program, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/BewaesserungssystemV3/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    jsondata = json.load(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 14 column 9 (char 316)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks, Jannis

Comment: JSON doesn't allow trailing commas in an object definition. The comma is an element *separator*, not an element *terminator*. What you have simply isn't valid JSON, just very JSON-like.

Comment: I thought that values like integers or boleans don`t have to be enclosed in double quotes?

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Trailing commas _are_ legal in JSON5, so if you cannot change the input file itself, you can use e.g. [the `pyjson5` package](https://pypi.org/project/pyjson5/) to parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the comma after the last value ie day: 0.
You can use JSON online validator if you encounter problems like these in the future.

```
{
    "main": {
        "active": true,
        "watering": false,
        "fwatering": false,
        "ffminwatering": false,
        "humidity": 24,
        "temp": 17.6,
        "battery": 100,
        "logging": true,
        "last_watering": "27.08.2021 16:15:39",
        "l_day": 0,
        "day": 0
    }
}
```